# ubuntu can not ping

Tags: networking, server

I have two servers.

OS: Ubuntu Server 12.04

Server1: HP Dl380
Server2: Blade server (it is not Virtual machine)

Server1 IP: 202.xxx.xxx.11
Server2 IP: 202.xxx.xxx.25

**Server1 and Server2 are in the same network segment and use the same switch 
but Server1 can not connect to Server2, and Server2 can not connect to Server1. How can I fix this issue?**

Server1 ping Server2

```
PING 202.xxx.xxx.25 (202.xxx.xxx.25) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 202.xxx.xxx.11 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Server2 ping Server1

```
PING 202.xxx.xxx.11 (202.xxx.xxx.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 202.xxx.xxx.25 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Server1 `arp -a`

```
? (202.a.b.c) at 00:1a:64:a1:2a:22 [ether] on eth0
?......
```

## nerver find server2

Server2 arp -a

```
? (202.a.b.c) at 00:1a:64:a1:2a:22 [ether] on eth0
?  (202.xxx.xxx.11) at <incomplete> on eth0
#can not get Server IP.
```

config:

Server1:

```
#/etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
#auto eth1
#iface eth1 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet static
address 202.XXX.XXX.11
netmask 255.255.255.128
gateway 202.XXX.XXX.1
dns-nameservers 202.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Server2:

```
#/etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
#auto eth1
#iface eth1 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet static
address 202.XXX.XXX.25
netmask 255.255.255.128
gateway 202.XXX.XXX.1
dns-nameservers 202.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Server1 ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr address
      inet addr:202.xxx.xxx.11  Bcast:202.xxx.xxx.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
      inet6 addr: address Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5528 errors:0 dropped:2352 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8381 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:517812 (517.8 KB)  TX bytes:1095962 (1.0 MB)
      Interrupt:16 Memory:f4000000-f4012800

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:2377 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2377 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:737914 (737.9 KB)  TX bytes:737914 (737.9 KB)
```

Server2 ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr address
      inet addr:202.xxx.xxx.25  Bcast:202.xxx.xxx.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
      inet6 addr: address Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6057 errors:0 dropped:723 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7872 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:489060 (489.0 KB)  TX bytes:988220 (988.2 KB)
      Interrupt:16 Memory:dfa00000-dfa20000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:25222 (25.2 KB)  TX bytes:25222 (25.2 KB)

 #Manufacturer direct installation KVM, direct use default Settings, no change

 virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:12:91:df:da:ac
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

## Server1 lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gi
gabit Ethernet [14e4:1639] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company NC382i Integrated Multi-port PCI Expr
ess Gigabit Server Adapter [103c:7055]
        Kernel driver in use: bnx2
--
03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gi
gabit Ethernet [14e4:1639] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company NC382i Integrated Multi-port PCI Expr
ess Gigabit Server Adapter [103c:7055]
        Kernel driver in use: bnx2
--
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gi
gabit Ethernet [14e4:1639] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company NC382i Integrated Multi-port PCI Expr
ess Gigabit Server Adapter [103c:7055]
        Kernel driver in use: bnx2
--
04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gi
gabit Ethernet [14e4:1639] (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company NC382i Integrated Multi-port PCI Expr
ess Gigabit Server Adapter [103c:7055]
        Kernel driver in use: bnx2
```

## Server2

```
nection [8086:10d3]
        Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Device [15d9:0000]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Con
nection [8086:10d3]
        Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Device [15d9:0000]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
```

I can ping Server1 and Server2 on the Internet.

Comment: i had fix it.Is a router problem